# customizing basic existing Django apps that already have "nice looking" CSS/HTML templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am looking for a basic Django application that "looks good" and has basic menus etc. that I could adapt for my own use.  I am not doing any fancy processing of user input, but I do want to reuse an existing templates so that I don't have to worry about writing my own CSS/HTML to get clean, valid good looking webpages.  Many of the Django websites themselves have a formatting that I could adapt, but I do not see anywhere an archive of templates.

Is there such an archive, where users post their templates for other Django users to adapt, kind of like Wordpress has many templates?

Examples of nice looking websites about Django that it'd be helpful to have templates for:

1. http://www.django-apps.com/browse/
2. The Django website itself: http://www.djangoproject.com/  -- looks great.

I think Django is a great framework for writing the actual content of the web app. My problem is that I want to start with a base that has the template already in Django's template, because I am not a web designer and I don't want to reinvent the wheel of writing nice looking HTML / CSS for a simple website that just has a couple of menu items.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is really in no way django-specific. I think you would be better suited if you search for something like "web templates download" in your favourite search engine. Find a layout that you like, pay for it (if you can't find anything gratis) and use it.

Oh, and no, there is regrettably no such archive (yet).